# How to change the reference in a function

Tags: java

In the following code snippet p is a node in a binary search tree, if the left child of p is not null I want to change p to point to its left child, but java is pass-by-value, when the function returns the structure of the tree remains unchanged.

```
void remove(BSTNode p)
{
    if(p.ch[0]==null)
        p=p.ch[0];
}
```

Actually I want to implement something like the following C++ code:

```
void remove(BSTNode* &p)
{
    if(p->ch[0]==NULL)
        p=p->ch[0];
}
```

For other reasons I don't want to use the following way to return p.ch[0] and set p after every call to remove.

```
BSTNode remove(BSTNode p)
{
    if(p.ch[0]==null)
        return p.ch[0];
}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a pointer to the nodes parent ant then change it using that reference

```
void remove(BSTNode p)
{
    if(p.ch[0]==null){
    p.parent.ch[0] = p.ch[0];
}
```

Comment: This is a way around, but we have to handle the case that p.parent doesn't exist, this will make the logic somewhat peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple wrapper:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    public T value;
}

void remove(Wrapper<BSTNode> p)
{
    if(p.value.ch[0] == null)
        p.value = p.value.ch[0];
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but does this will slow down the performance a lot if we have a great deal of this kind of operations ?

Comment: @outlaw: Not really, since they're all references. Instead of passing a reference to `BSTNode` you pass one to `Wrapper`. Same size, same operations involved.

Comment: But every time we want to pass a reference to BSTNode we have to new a Wrapper<BSTNode> and set value to p, in a recursive function there might be a lot of such allocations.

Comment: @outlaw: For the calling code you are right unfortunately, you'll need another set of references. I thought you meant for the method itself. Anyway, try to see if you can reuse the same wrapper for multiple `BSTNode`s by just changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a reference and changing it simply won't have any effect in Java, you will only change the new local reference.
In spite of your other reasons, I would suggest you go with your last approach.

Another way to solve it is to pass in the parent node of `p`, and change the reference in that object.

Comment: I don't want to use the lass approach because it will make the code very messy when so many functions are implemented recursively.

Answer (score 1):

@outlaw, As you may know, Java doesn't support pointers. I don't know much about your requirement, but I have faced this kind of situation many times. Usually what I do is: instead of assignment (`p = p.ch[0]`) transfer properties of `p.ch[0] to p`.